# Check if particular value exists in my users node

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I iterate throught all the users node, I just want to send notifications to the users who have shop as a value inside the document, if there is users that dont have this attribute inside the document I dont want to send them a notification

```
exports.rememberToOpenStore = functions.pubsub.schedule('30 09 * * *').onRun(async (context) => {
    var db = admin.firestore();
    let snap = await db.collection('user').get();
                return snap.forEach((doc) => {
                    if(doc.data().shop !== null){
                        const deviceToken = doc.data().deviceToken
                        const payload = {
                        notification: {
                            title: "Good morning ! ",
                            body: "Remember to open your store."
                        }
                    }
                    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken,payload)
                    }
                    return null;
            });
});
```

I want to know if this

```
if(doc.data().shop !== null)
```

will do the trick to know which user has or not that attribute

Is there a better way to do this with a where query with something like

```
let snap = await db.collection('user').where("shop" "!=", null).get();
```

to just get users that have that shop value inside the docuement ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about the values that `shop` may have, but according to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) you could `orderBy` a field and if it doesn't exist it will not be returned. Thus, querying Firestore ordering by the field `shop` will not return the documents that don't contain said field.

The query should be something like this:

```
db.collection('user').orderBy('shop').get()
```

Another option would be creating the field for all the documents and assigning it a `null` value. This way you could also retrieve the documents that *have* said field.

In this case the query should be something like this:

```
db.collection('user'),where('shop', '!=', null).get()
```